# Not sure if this is right programming using spring TaskExecutor

Tags: spring

I just came up with something funny code

```
public class FeedService {

    @Inject
    private FriendService friendService;

    @Inject
    private FeedRepository feedRepository;

    private ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor;

    public FeedService(){
        prepareExecutor();
    }

    @Async
    public void addToFriendsFeed(final Status status, User user) {
        Collection<String> friends = friendService.getFriendsForUser(user.getLogin());
        for (final String friend : friends) {
             taskExecutor.execute( new Runnable() {
                   public void run() {
                       feedRepository.createFeed(friend, Constants.FEED_STATUS, status.getStatusId());
                   }
              });
        }
    }



public Executor prepareExecutor() {
        taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(2);
        taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(10);
        taskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(25);
        taskExecutor.setThreadNamePrefix("FeedServiceExecutor-");
        taskExecutor.initialize();
        return taskExecutor;
    }
}
```

I am not sure if this code is right.? Any spring gurus could you please let me know...
I am not able to understand the executor part.. I am not sure if i need to create a ThreadPool when i am doing new Runnable each time...I am not a threading expert thats why I posted ..if i already knew it than i haven't posted it...

Comment: I am not able to understand the executor part.. I am not sure if i need to create a ThreadPool when i am doing new Runnable each time...I am not a threading expert thats why I posted ..if i already knew it than i haven't posted it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `TaskExecutor` will be `null` as you haven't initialized it.

Your `prepareExecutor()` method creates a `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` which it assigns to a local variable and then returns. You do nothing with that return value. Did you mean to assign it to `taskExecutor`?

You would probably want to inject the `TaskExecutor` instead of creating it within this service.

Comment: You are right..i updated the code...but what differnce it will make if i inject it...

Comment: @SaurabhKumar Not much. Separation of Concerns. You're already using Dependency Injection. Might as well use it fully. Is a `Service` really responsible for creating a `TaskExecutor`? I would say no.